# Replace text in a pdf file in Python using Fitz

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

Does anyone have tried before to replace text from a PDF File using Fitz of PyMuPDF Library ?

i have tried to use the code below and i am not sure if i am close to the result or it's impossible to use using this library:

```
import fitz

file_name = 'D:/DOSSIERS/pdf_file.pdf'

with fitz.Document(file_name) as doc:
  for page in doc:
    for xref in page.get_contents():
        stream = doc.xref_stream(xref).replace(b'mis',b'kjhkj')
        doc.update_stream(xref, stream)
```

Comment: Manipulating content streams like that only works for pdfs with a special, simple internal structure.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! i only have to replace text in a PDF with simple internal structure.

Comment: Ok, so if you apply your code to your test file, does 'mis' get replaced by 'kjhkj'? If not, the internal structure of the PDF may not be simple enough.